# Returning/Chaining variables vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, return

Id like to have VB.Net code written like this.

Module1.run(parameters,parameters)
">> Passing parameters to module2 >>"
Module2.run(parameters,parameters)

Essentially passing parameters between modules without running a module via a return statement, or multiple statements in this case. And avoiding shared public registers.  Is this even possible? Can I pass variables in the module header maybe?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class `MyParameters`

```
Public Class MyParameters
    'Add any inputs / outputs
    Public AnInput As Integer
    Public AnOutput As String
End Class
```

Define `Module1.Run` as

```
Public Sub Run(ByVal args As MyParameters)
    args.AnOutput = String.Format("The user passed {0}", args.AnInput)
End Sub
```

Define 'Module2.Run' as

```
Public Sub Run(ByVal args As MyParameters)
    Msgbox(args.AnOutput)
End Sub
```

Then you can call with:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim args = New MyParameters() With {.AnInput = 5}
    Module1.Run(args)
    Module2.Run(args)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured part1 out. The thing I'll have to do is pass the arguments by reference. By putting the ByRef keyword in the module header. And make an extra variable to store the bidirectional variable. "strange way to set the data direction if you ask me"

Anyway, is there a way I can use the variable supplied by the header, since I can control which instance of the called class is used where? To save some variables there.

Regards,